# How to disable default trim in writing variable ejs, node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angularjs, ejs

When I writing variable in EJS table from database, it is written by ejs template with default trim. I want to write variable that come database without default trim.

I examined ejs template document(https://ejs.co) but they did not help me.

`<%- fetchpost[i].p_content %>` -> with HTML

`<%= fetchpost[i].p_content %>` -> only string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EJS doesn't seem to trim data by default. If your content has spaces, they should be preserved. I created a test for this:
https://noderun.com/alex/ejs-trim-test/

However, HTML doesn't render multiple spaces in a row when rendered by a browser (that could be your problem). In that case you could try:

```
<%- content.replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;") %>
```

This replaces spaces with HTML non-breaking spaces.

Comment: Also, other users can <pre></pre> tags and style="white-space: pre;" feature to solve this problem.